# No such file or directory error when starting UNetbootin in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unetbootin

I have a problem starting UNetbootin from the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04. I got this error message.

```
./unetbootin-linux-608: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `libsm6` but it was already installed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to download unetbootin-linux-608 from any source, except from the official Ubuntu repositories. There is a better version of UNetbootin in the Ubuntu Software Center, or else you can install it from the terminal using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

You will not have any issues with loading shared libraries if you install this version.

UNetbootin has been dropped from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. When I tested the built-in Startup Disk Creator application as a UNetbootin replacement app with a non-*buntu live .iso image it worked in Ubuntu 18.04. Startup Disk Creator is my choice for a replacement for UNetbootin in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.